# MSOpenTech Redis – Multiple instances on same machine

Tags: windows, redis

I’m using the windows redis port form Microsoft ([GitHub](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis)).
How can I run multiple instances of redis on the same machine?
Can I use the same binaries and configure a port per instance or do I need to install the binaries (in a different directory) for each instance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok this is how it works:

- Make a copy of the existing config file *"C:\Program Files\Redis\redis.windows-service.conf"* named *"C:\Program Files\Redis\redis.windows-service-new.conf"*
- **Change** the **port** and other settings like logfile and syslog-ident
- Run the following command to create a new service:

Command:

```
sc create Redis2 obj= "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" start= auto DisplayName= "Redis2" binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\Redis\redis-server.exe\" --service-run \"C:\Program Files\Redis\redis.windows-service-new.conf\"
```

Comment: I am trying to run 25 instances of Redis on the same machine. But, after starting few the rest don't start. even the started one don't stop. any suggestions please

Comment: @bjan I wonder how you have started the 25 instances of Redis as I'm trying to run the two instances of Redis.

Comment: @VeswanthRaju I abandoned that solution of the problem, however as i remember older version of Redis was allowing to run multiple instances (processes) from multiple directories, newer version was not allowing at that time.

Comment: This needs to run from a command prompt instead of from Powershell

Answer (score 3):

You can run the same executable multiple times starting `redis-server` with different configurations, either using a file or by giving parameters. Obviously, the ports must be also different.

Comment: I am trying to run 25 instances of Redis on the same machine. But, after starting few the rest don't start. even the started one don't stop. any suggestions please

Comment: @bjan you'll need to ask a new question and provide more details

Comment: here is the question, kindly let me know what more details are required. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191455/redis-service-start-and-stop-is-failing

Comment: I have used below commands to run the multiple instances of Redis

`redis-server --service-install --service-name redis7 --port 2222`

`redis-server --service-start --service-name redis7`